# How can I bulk redirect post to homepage?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Until now I use wordpress plugin "redirection" to make redirect.

If I want make bulk redirection old article to new article I make csv that contain 2 columns for old url and new url.

So the columns looks like

```
/old-url/     /new-url/
```

but how if I want to bulk redirect `/old-url/` to homepage?

What should I write in my csv?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what result did you get? It seems to me that you should still be able to just redirect the old url to the new url, even if the new url happens to be your home page.

Answer (score 0):

Homepage is /, so change /new-url/ to /